# Disable the "question with the same title" filter on Arqade

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking

When trying to ask [What does Luck do in Hyperdimension Neptunia mk2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96959/what-does-luck-do-in-hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2) I found there was already a question titled "What does luck do?" No biggie, it was a completely different game (tag based suggestions already please). But I found I couldn't submit the question with that title because another question already had it.

There's got to be at least 500 different games where "What does luck do?" is a legitimate question, and while appending the game title to the question title works around the blocker I don't think that should be necessary. The tags clearly indicate the game in any question list and the general consensus seems to be "you don't need to include the game's title in the question at all times" unless it's organic.

This seems like a rather pointless restriction for a site like Arqade where it's quite easy to ask a completely different question (due to tags) with an identical title, so could this feature be switched off for Arqade? Alternately it'd be agreeable if the filter were limited to questions with tags in common (but non-game tags like DLC would still potentially screw that up)

Comment: While I agree this would be nice, I would consider that there might be a *technical* reason to prevent questions from having the same title, which may make this request unfeasible.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I think the duplicate title restriction was implemented later, not from the beginning. So I think removing it should be technically possible.

Comment: @RavenDreamer doubtful; the primary key in the DB is a post id,  so unless they actually have a unique constraint on the post title too  (if what Mad Scienist points out is true, they probably haven't) it shouldn't be a technical thing.

Comment: @BenBrocka I wouldn't expect it to be the primary key, sure, but I have a feeling it might get used in searching / hashing. Though given the state of SE search, no big loss on its removal, eh? :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer they're actually overhauling search apparently. But titles shouldn't need to be unique, especially not if they focus on Tags more, which they need to for suggested questions at the very least

Comment: And of course, since we have the 'lovely' addition of the top two tags appending onto the title anyway.

Comment: Could be a double post issue. On many sites if you press the "submit" button many times before the server can handle the request you end up with the same question/post multiple times. One way to prevent this is to make the title unique.

Comment: @ayckoster they have a validator that doesn't let you post a word-for word duplicate already

Comment: @ayckoster Actually I think people still can trigger this if they hit things at precisely the right time, even with our restrictions.

Comment: I don't see why it would be so difficult to keep current functionality but add exceptions based on tags.  So, you could have multiple questions with the same title, but only 1 per tag.  It seems highly likely questions can duplicate, especially in cases of sequels.

Comment: Related: [Please show tags in the list of suggested questions that may already have your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170056/162827)