# Proposed edit rejected because it is too minor

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[My suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32855) was rejected because it was too minor. The change I made is indeed technically minor; I just removed the "NWN2" part of the title since it is already included as a tag. While I just removed a few letters from the title, I have always thought that removing "tags" from the question title is not *that* minor.

Also, if you read the question body, what else is there to correct? It's absolutely fantastic in my opinion. The question is clear, well-researched, and with links even.

Two things:

1. Is removing tags from question titles really *that* minor?
2. If there is only one small thing that is wrong with a question, should we not bother correcting them then because it is "too minor"?

Comment: For what it's worth, this edit was rejected 2-1, so the community was not agreed on the edit.

Comment: @RavenDreamer but which way should it have gone? The question author was one of the rejections even.

Answer (score 8):

Removing tags (i.e. the name of the game) from a title is too minor an edit when the text of the question flows well with the name in it.

**Good Example:**
How do I get infinite lives in Game X?

**Bad Example:**
Game X: How do I get infinite lives?

LessPop's question was of the first form, so the title should be left alone, especially as there were absolutely no other changes required to the question.

This was recently discussed on meta - see Mad Scientist's answer here:
[When should we edit game names out of question titles? And why?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why)

Comment: According to that answer, it's ok if the title is generic without the game name in the title and/or the title won't be too long. In this particular question, it's far from being generic without the game name and question title is already too long even without it.

Comment: @rikitikitik - Regardless, it's still a minor edit, which is why your suggested edit was rejected.

Comment: So are you saying that a *minor* edit should not be done even if it's the only thing wrong with a question?

Comment: Yes.  That is official SE policy and the reason why suggested edits can be rejected as "too minor".  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review?rq=1.

Comment: Does that have a higher priority over [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/179519) that is included in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)? Also, that link is about tiny edits, capitalizing small letters, etc, on questions that have multiple possible edits that were not included. That isn't the case here.

Comment: Not really.  Both rules can apply.  Tags don't need to be forced into question titles (though you really can argue about whether <problem> in <game> is forcing), but removing a forced tag can also be a minor edit that doesn't need to be done in isolation, which is the point of the meta Q&A I linked in my previous comment.  Isolation applies whether you skip making other valid edits, or if there are no other valid edits to make.

Comment: I don't agree with Jason Berkan's original principle. Judgment of flow is subjective. I like to write in the style of the "bad" example (A.K.A. HK-47 style) and frankly, I find the judgment of that style as "bad", to be offensive. If rikitikitik isn't incorrect in interpreting that title length matters, then I also disagree with the longer title being the "good" example. It might help to consider Wikipedia protocol, but that's tough for me to say since I'm being hyprocritical in neglecting to learn it right now.

Comment: @NiteCyper I'm coming in a bit late here, but it's not about flow, it's about search results.  Tags are prepended to the page title, so Google will show "Game X - Game X: How do I get infinite lives?", which is redundant and annoying, and in the case of longer tags it may even truncate much of the descriptive part of the title.  It's not good for getting clicks.