# Why was my edit of a question title rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

As far as I understand, putting the name of a game (aka a [tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag)) in a title is not needed at all, unless its in the flow of the question.
Yet [one of my edits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/171567) was rejected because:  *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."*

I understand it was not a major edit and that the reject comment is correct in some way, but I still followed the guidelines. (i think)
According to these 2 threads on the meta, my edit was valid.

- [Proposed edit rejected because it is too minor](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/proposed-edit-rejected-because-it-is-too-minor)
- [When should we edit game names out of question titles and why](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why)

And even [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208) it says that question titles should not be "tag: question title"

I don't want to go around making bad or unnecessary edits, but I am under the impression that I was doing a valid edit.

Was I or was I not?

Comment: I would've changed it to "How to execute a stunned zombie in Dying Light?" as executing a zombie could be ambiguous as to which game. If I were to be Google'ing the question, I would be typing something similar to "execute stunned zombie dying light" and it would be harder to find if the title isn't mentioned in the question, especially if multiple game has a similar mechanic.

Comment: @Dragonrage not necessarily, it will take the tagging into account with teh search, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @AshleyNunn did not realize it took the tag into account. However it would seem to help alleviate this http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why sort of thing when showing possible dups when asking a question

Comment: @Dragonrage i just googled "How to execute a stunned zombie?" and the question was the first in the list. Still i understand your point that instead of just removing the tag from the title, i should rewrite the title to incorporate the tag perhaps

Comment: The edit was probably rejected because @TimPost [lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught) again.

Comment: I might have rejected that edit as being too minor. Probably would have. It's a waste of people's time to put such a minor edit in the review queue. If you want to make a tiny nitpicky edit once you have 2k rep, go for it.

Answer (score 6):

Your edit was perfectly fine, and should not have been rejected, and yet it has been, presumably because [Tim Post lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught) again.

I have decided to edit the question myself now, going with @Dragonrage's proposal of appending the game name, although it's not strictly necessary. No game title in the title would have been perfectly fine, too, since "execute stunned zombie" is sufficiently distinct phrasing, similar to "Dragon Bones and Scales".

Comment: Thankx, but how does one best respond to valid edits being rejected? i understand at 2k rep i will no longer have to worry about such situations but until then? Re editing is not recommended and making a meta thread everything seems like a lot of unnecessary hassle.

Comment: @Vahx - Pretty much just like this, raise it on meta and/or in chat. It shouldn't be a situation that comes up too often though...

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that it was rejected for being too minor. Whether it's correct to conclude that or not could be argued either way, but it's definitely not some inscrutable random event.