# Questions fitting more than one game

Tags: discussion, questions

Due to the nature of some games, it is possible (even inevitable) that some questions would fit more than one game. It is customary [not to add game name to question title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why), however questions that only differ by tags can't be posted. And so we get something like this:

[Are there any time-based events?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30688/are-there-any-time-based-events)

[Are there any time-sensitive events in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40088/are-there-any-time-sensitive-events-in-skyrim)

And my recent creation: [Are there any time-based events in Pillars of Eternity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213416/are-there-any-time-based-events-in-pillars-of-eternity)

Is that to be expected? How should I proceed if I find a question title that perfectly fits what I want to ask, but is connected to a different game and therefore taken?

Comment: The main thing to avoid in using a title in the name is non-naturalistic formats like "SKYRIM: time Sensitive events?" If the sentence you write feels natural, it's generally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually outlined in the post you linked. From the [top-voted answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6951/8350):

> In cases like this, where the question itself is completely generic and applies to many games, adding the title perfectly acceptable, it might be even necessary to circumvent the duplicate title check (you can't have two questions with exactly the same title on the site).

Our "rule" about no game name in the title isn't strict either, it's just that we prefer the name to not be in the title if it's not needed. It helps keeps the titles shorter, and in some cases make them feel more natural.