# Should the name Think-Different and the level number be included in Think-Different question titles?

Tags: discussion

Should we include both the title and level number in the title for these questions? It seems like both are needed to distinguish between questions. Stuck on level (a common phrase in [think-different](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/think-different) question titles) is not sufficiently unique IMO, to distinguish between games (relevant [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why)) and the level seems to be needed to distinguish between different [think-different](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/think-different) questions.

Comment: Note this discussion was brought up by [this edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/172385) that was approved where the level and question number was suggested to be taken out of the title and into the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 100% agree that the title should have the level and question numbers in it. It's unfortunate that so many questions do not have these numbers which will make it difficult to find duplicate questions.

As for putting the game title into the question that I feel is less important but according to the [highest answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6951/106901) on the meta you posted it is good to do so because of the ambiguity demonstrated in the image on that meta question.

If [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/please-show-tags-in-the-list-of-suggested-questions-that-may-already-have-your-a) feature was implemented I would say that we shouldn't include the game title in the question title. But since it isn't (and doesn't look like it will be) then I feel the best course is to put it into the question title.

Comment: However, I believe it should fit naturally into the title. Questions with [Game Title]: [Actual Question?] come off as an eye sore and are often (not always) unnecessary in that case. Something like [How do I solve this level 72 question in Think Different?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248279/how-do-i-solve-this-level-72-question-in-think-different) works better IMO.